# Are all Y-chromosomes the same?

Tags: dna, sex-chromosome, dna-replication

Since the Y-chromosome can only pass from male to male child, it would seem to pass intact. Thus, a boy's Y-chromosomes would, I guess, be the same as his father's. Going backwards, would not all men have identical Y-chromosomes for this reason, being somewhat like mitochondrial DNA?

Comment: Because the Y stops recombining and has a small population size it is expected that variation will be rapidly depleted.  Mutations still occur on the Y which can maintain some within population variance. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26230387

Comment: There is a difference between an *evolutionary process* and a *genetic process* so to speak: you don't need recombination for evolution. A lot of organisms use *cloning* to generate "offspring", but these evolve as well because of mutation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, no. There are also recombination prone regions of the Y chromosome that recombine and exchange material with X chromosomes, and these are called [pseudoautosomal regions (PARs)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8225310).

Y chromosomes can be used similarly to mitochondrial DNA [to build up profiles of ancestry](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v26/n3/full/ng1100_358.html), but the sequences used for this purpose lie outside PARs, in the non-recombining region.

*What about seqeuences outside PARs, do they show genetic variation?*

As pointed out in the comments, PARs comprise only 5% of the Y chromosome, but even in the non-recombining regions of the Y chromosome studies in well-characterised populations have found that the mutation rate can approximate [autosomal mutation rates in some regions of the chromosome, and exceed them in others.](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v47/n5/full/ng.3171.html)

*What processes, other than recombination, drive mutations?*

There are loads of different mechanisms by which mutations in general can be generated, including exposure to UV, free radicals, tobacco smoke, aristolochic acid, and perhaps most importantly spontaenous deamination of methylcytosines, which is an age related mutational process, proofreading errors inherent to DNA polymerases. Also, it is well known that in [sperm, with age the mutation rate goes up throughout the genome](http://www.nature.com/news/fathers-bequeath-more-mutations-as-they-age-1.11247). While UV is unlikely to be a prominent mutagen as was pointed out to me in the comments insofar sperm are concerned, factors like [smoking still play a role](http://humupd.oxfordjournals.org/content/6/2/122.full.pdf).

An illuminating read about mutational processes and the mutational footprints they leave in genomes, as understood from studying cancer genomes, [is here](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v500/n7463/full/nature12477.html).

Comment: Ok, but those regions are only 5% of the chromosome. Is the other 95% the same in all men?

Comment: Nope - those regions too are subjected to mutations at various rates, that in some well characterised populations approximate the autosomal mutation rate in some regions of the Y chromosome, with other regions showing elevated mutation rates. 

http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v47/n5/full/ng.3171.html

Comment: Without recombination, how is the chromosome mutating? I know that it might get struck by a cosmic ray or something, but barring that, how?

Comment: There are loads of different mechanisms by which mutations can be generated, including exposure to UV, free radicals, tobacco smoke, aristolochic acid, and perhaps most importantly spontaenous deamination of methylcytosines, which is an age related mutational process, proofreading errors inherent to DNA polymerases. 

Also, it is well known that in sperm, with age the mutation rate goes up throughout the genome. http://www.nature.com/news/fathers-bequeath-more-mutations-as-they-age-1.11247

Comment: One of the places where mutational processes and signatures have been best studied is in cancers; and this paper should make for illuminating reading. http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v500/n7463/full/nature12477.html

Comment: I am not sure if you can have UV exposure on your list, as I do not think it is likely that UV has the energy to penetrated deep enough into the tissue to cause damage to germline cells, which is the only way to pass on mutations. More energetic EM waves such as X-rays obviously could do the damage, but there you start to have to think about how much damage can be done before the sperm is ineffective. I am also not sure if there are mutagenic effects to germline cells from tobacco smoke. I could see where you might get decreased fertility due to vascular changes. I agree with the others.

Comment: @AnkurChakravarthy please can you edit all of your comments into the body of your answer: they make it a much stronger answer, and it means they will be preserved long after the comments are deleted (comments are ephemeral, questions and answers are to keep)

Comment: @ImprisonedRhesus That's what mutation *is*. Crossovers and similar "operations" are not mutation - only DNA damage is. Apart from what Ankur already mentioned, there's a few more interesting ways - for example, errors when *repairing* damaged DNA. By far most of those happen in your somatic cells, of course, so they are not long-living, and they do not propagate to your offspring, but there's still plenty that affect your germ cells (not to mention possibly affecting the development of an embryo, where there's a chance to affect the whole organism rather than just a cell or two).

Comment: @AMR It's not about having too little energy, really - visible light penetrates far deeper than UV. But other than that, I think you're right - the deepest penetrating UVA only penetrates about 4mm. It *might* be possible a small amount penetrates deep enough to affect germ cells, but probably not significant enough to matter.

Comment: @AMR I don't think you read my comment right - visible light (lower energy than UV) penetrates *deeper*. It's not a matter of bigger energy penetrating deeper - rather, it's about the energy levels available for absorption (after all, how else would different materials be transparent to different spectra of light?). If you want to know how X-ray imaging *actually* works, it's a very interesting subject (bones are indeed absorbing a lot of X-rays, but we get a lot more information from scattering, which also happens in soft tissue).

Comment: @Luaan you are correct about absorption, I was mixing my arguments. This figure illustrates your point well. http://ec.europa.eu/health/scientific_committees/opinions_layman/artificial-light/en/figtableboxes/8.htm

Comment: AMR - I agree UV is likely to be a weak contributor to germline mutations. Smoking on the other hand has been shown to be a germline mutagen (see http://humupd.oxfordjournals.org/content/6/2/122.full.pdf) 

EnergyNumbers I will make that edit.